# Plotly + ggplot2: Adding a layer can make tool tips disappear

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly

Using ggplot2 and plotly, I can easily create a US county choropleth and set custom tool tips. However, when I add state boundaries, tool tips fail to render in *some* situations. The problem seems to be linked to proximity to the state boundary. What might be causing this, and how do I fix it?

First, an example where adding the second layer completely breaks tool tips.

```
library(plotly)
library(tidyverse)

### One layer -- works fine
a <- data.frame(group = seq(3085), val = rnorm(3085)) %>%
  left_join(ggplot2::map_data("county"), by = "group")

p <- ggplot(a, aes(long, lat, group = group)) +
  geom_polygon(aes(fill = val, text = subregion))

ggplotly(p, tooltip="text")

### Two layers -- no tool tips
b <- ggplot2::map_data("state")

p <- ggplot(a, aes(long, lat, group = group)) +
  geom_polygon(aes(fill = val, text = subregion)) +
  geom_path(data = b, color = "black")

ggplotly(p, tooltip="text")
```

When I use a much smaller choropleth (one state), the tool tips display normally even with two layers.

```
### Just Delaware: shows tool tips
b <- ggplot2::map_data("state") %>%
  filter(region == "delaware")

a <- data.frame(group = seq(3085), val = rnorm(3085)) %>%
  left_join(ggplot2::map_data("county"), by = "group") %>%
  filter(region == "delaware")

p <- ggplot(a, aes(long, lat, group = group)) +
  geom_polygon(aes(fill = val, text = subregion)) +
  geom_path(data = b, color = "black")

ggplotly(p, tooltip="text")
```

A medium-size choropleth with two layers displays tool tips far from the state boundary, but not close to it.

```
### New England: *sometimes* shows tool tips
new_england <- c("maine", "new hampshire", "vermont", "massachusetts", "connecticut", "rhode island")
b <- ggplot2::map_data("state") %>%
  filter(region %in% new_england)

a <- data.frame(group = seq(3085), val = rnorm(3085)) %>%
  left_join(ggplot2::map_data("county"), by = "group") %>%
  filter(region %in% new_england)

p <- ggplot(a, aes(long, lat, group = group)) +
  geom_polygon(aes(fill = val, text = subregion)) +
  geom_path(data = b, color = "black")

ggplotly(p, tooltip="text")
```

I noticed that switching to "compare data on hover" solves the problem, but this is asking too much of my readers unless there is a way to turn this on by default.

Comment: I can't get even the first one to run for me (it may be due to changes in the dev version of ggplot), but I suspect the issue is your later layers are covering up your previous ones. Whatever gets added last ends up on top, so try adding the counties after the states.

Comment: If you add the counties after the states, the fill (from the geom_polygon) is drawn over the line (from the geom_path), so it doesn't work in that order. I am using ggplot2_2.1.0. I confirmed that if you install plotly with the dev ggplot2, you get an error.